# How can i know the QTreeView is empty?

Tags: pyqt

I'm using QTreeView with QDirModel to list the contents of a directory.. When a user selects an item(or a row) i'm removing it from the tree view using the below method

> setRowHidden (self, int, QModelIndex,
>   bool)

How can i know that the tree view is empty or all rows are hidden?? Rowcount and Columncount doesn't seem to help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all items and check if them are hidden with QTreView.isRowHidden(int, QModelIndex).

It is the only way. But why do you hide rows instead of removing them?